# How to get started with RadPHP XE2 and Android?

Tags: android, cordova, radphp

I have installed RadPHP XE2 on a Windows 7 Professional 64-bit host.
I ran the Android-setup.exe. Using the SDK manager i have downloaded all available packages and created an Android 2.2 (API Level 8) device.

I opened the PhoneGap examples, ran the "Wizard for Phonegap". Set Android as target device, Set the index page,icons and destination folder. The Export completes.

I select "Emulator". The Emulator drop down is empty. So i enter the path to the emulator (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\emulator.exe)

The console output gives a warning :Attribute minSdkVersion in AndroidManifest.xml (2) is lower than the target API level (3). I cannot find anywhere to change the API level (or device for that matter). The AndroidManifest.xml gets overwritten at export.

Also 5 different resource identifier errors for aapt.exe : "No resource identifier found for attribute 'largeScreens' in package 'a  <-I can't read the rest of the line as it is cut off in the console output window, which i can't resize or scroll!!

It seems like i have some kind of setup problem, but where can I find a "Getting started" or some other info on how to check the setup ?

The documentation for RadPHP seems quite limited. Searching the help for either Phonegap or Android returns zero results :o(

Best regards

Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is fixed into update1. Uninstall everything related to Android, install android-setup. When installing android-sdk not download anything from the sdk-manager, deselect the option and exit.

Comment: Thanks - it worked (sorry about the late response - I somehow forgot to reply when I saw your answer)